# run liquibase on multiple databases at different versions

Tags: database, liquibase

I am trying to integrate Liquibase with our Spring/Hibernate web-app to replace our existing home-grown solution. So far Liquibase is great, but there's one use-case that is important to us and I don't know if Liquibase supports it or not,  which is this:

We deploy our web app  to clients who host the webapp and the database (MySQL) themselves. So, supposing we deploy to our first client (client1) with a new clean DB schema ( generated from Hibernate mappings) and no items in Liquibase changeset. We then develop some schema changes and redeploy the application to client1, and liquibase does its stuff  and applies the changesets- all great so far.

Now, we deploy to  a new client, client2, again with a new database schema generated from Hibernate mappings. But this time, there are changesets present ( for the changes made between client1 and client2 deployments)  but they don't need to be applied, as  they're already in the new schema). However, because the DATABASECHANGELOG table is empty, Liquibase will try to apply the changesets and probably fail with SQL errors.
What we'd like is for new deployments to new clients to 'know' at what changeset they are (relative to the first deployment to client 1), so it only applies subsequent updates.

There seem to be several possibilities for this, probably more I've not thought of:

- populate DATABASECHANGELOG  with fake entries to fool Liquibase into thinking these have already been applied.
- always deploy our first,baseline original schema to subsequent clients, and run updates sequentially, and so never deploy a 'new'  schema derived from Hibernate mappings, after client1.
- use our own tracking system (e.g., map a db version to an application version, and a db version to a changeset).

Is this a problem, or I am just not understanding how to use Liquibase properly? Would be grateful for any advice from people who've dealt with this sort of use-case before. We'd really like to avoid deployment-specific changeSets if at all possible - there will be dozens, if not hundreds of deployments to handle.

Thanks, 
 Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a similar setup. 
But we are getting liquibase into the game earlier. Before we officially release the software we setup the liquibase changesets and let liquibase handle the database.

We did not want to loose the advantage of letting hibernate generate the DB during the development phase. So we are also using Hibernate while developing.

But right before the version is stable we let the liquibase diff tool run on the database and let it create a changeset for the hibernate-generated tables. 
Then this changeset is corrected manually since the liquibase diff tool does produce some flaws.

Once the changeset is ready we ship this with the software.

We maintain a reference system that keeps the data base version of the last officially released version. Then for the next release we let the liquibase diff tool run with the current development version against the reference db. That spits out the difference for the next version. This is also corrected manually and finally you have a changeset that changes the db to the next version.

Hope this gives you an idea of one way to use liquibase and hibernate together.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - we've set up a second dev-database that we can use to compare to the hibernate-generated tables and test out the liquibase updates, before committing, and we'll see how that works...

Answer (score 1):

I usually suggest always running the same changelog file against all your different databases. That way you don't have to deal with manually marking changeSets as ran, using preconditions, or anything else. Most importantly, every database will follow the same upgrade path so you know they are going to update consistently without any unexpected problems.

You can use the [liquibase hibernate extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki) to automatically append changeSets to your changelog based on your hibernate mapping, but when it comes time to deploy your changes to the databases you just run your liquibase changelog file and not try to use hibernate's schema generation logic at all.

Answer (score 0):

For option 1 above (populate with fake entries) I've just discovered the changelogSync command which looks like it marks all changeset entries as applied, even if they haven't been.

But is this better or worse than genuinely applying the changes, from a baseline schema?